# How to check on ajax success when the server response is true or false?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have server response which is `true` or `false`. I have been trying to figure out how to check on `success` if the returned value is `true` or `false` with the following script :

```
$('form[data-async]').on('submit', function(event) {
var $form = $(this);
var $target = $($form.attr('data-target'));

$("input#login").val('Connexion...');

$.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    cache: false,

    success: function(data) {
        if (data == true) {
            alert('success :  user logged in');
        } else {
            alert('Erreur login');
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});

event.preventDefault();
});
```

I have been trying all the possible value for data like `data == 'true' & data == 1` but still not working. Any idea please ?
Here is the called function :

```
        function login ($username, $password){
        if (!isset($_SESSION['vivvo'])){
            $_SESSION['vivvo'] = array();
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail_time']) && ($_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail_time'] < (VIVVO_START_TIME - 60*60))){
            $_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail'] = 0;
            $_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail_time'] = 0;
        }

        if ($_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail'] >= 3){
            $this->set_error_code(2751);
            return false;
        }

        $user_list = $this->get_user_list(null);
        $user = $user_list->get_user_data($username, $password);
        if ($user == false){
            $_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail'] = $_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail'] + 1;
            $_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail_time'] = time();
            if ($_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail'] >= 3){
                $this->set_error_code(2751);
            }elseif ($_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail'] >= 2){
                $this->set_error_code(2752);
            }else{
                $this->set_error_code(2753);
            }
            return false;
        }else{
            if ($user->get_activated() == '1'){
                $sm =& vivvo_lite_site::get_instance();
                $sm->user = $user;
                $sm->user->set_privileges();
                if (!isset($_SESSION['vivvo'])){
                    $_SESSION['vivvo'] = array();
                }
                $_SESSION['vivvo']['user_id'] = $sm->user->get_id();
                $_SESSION['vivvo']['user_domain'] = VIVVO_USER_SOURCE;
                $_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail'] = 0;
                $_SESSION['vivvo']['login_fail_time'] = 0;
                session_regenerate_id();
                return true;
            }else{
                $this->set_error_code(2754);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your `console.log (data);` output.

Comment: Have you checked what response you are getting using javascript debugging. You might be getting a complete HTTP Response object on which data is just a property. Try using data.data in your case. It might work

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. Do you mean to check if(data.data == true) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `dataType` attribute in your `AJAX` request. Include it

```
$.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType : 'html', //set the dataType attribute
    cache: false,

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); //Try to log the data and check the response
        if (data == true) {
            alert('success :  user logged in');
        } else {
            alert('Erreur login');
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

Then try to `console.log(data)` inside the `success` function to see what exactly are you recieving from the server.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in your `success` event, the `data` parameter usually represents elements within the response of your request, in the format of JSON. So, within the response, set a JSON object with a parameter called `returnValue` with either `true` or `false` value. Then, you could access this value via `data.returnValue`.

Moreover, note that you can see what is in the variable `data` using the following command: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` The contents of `data` will be printed in the debug terminal. If you wish to see an alert with the values of `data`, use the following command `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`.

In the server side function, it should return either `true` or `false`, using the following procedure:

```
funtion yourfunction() {

    ....

    $data = array( 'returnValue' => 'true');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Observe that you create a Map with the data you want to return and later echoed as JSON. Then, when accessing the `data` object in your `success` event, do either `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` or `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: Hi, the value returned is **undefined** whatever the user exist or not

Comment: So, you should check how you are returning data in your response. Would you mind sharing this in your question?

Comment: The called function is added.

Comment: If this answered your question, please check the green "checker" below the answer number. Thanks :)